# Clean list datatype in a dataframe column

Tags: python

I have a data that looks like the following:

```
Data 
[pineapple]
[pear]
[]
[chilli]
```

Values under data column are lists. May I know how can I clean it so that there is no brackets []?

Comment: Ok. How can we help?

Comment: What exactly do you want? What do you mean by "clean"?

Comment: Lists are a specific type of object, not brackets in a string. What do you want to do with the values? *It matters a lot* because Pandas offers various ways of dealing with this. You can leave them as is, you can expand them to multiple columns or rows, you can create one comma-separated string, for each list.

Comment: it it possible to change it to string instead of a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed your lists are lists of strings

```py
df['Data'] = df.Data.map(lambda x: x[0])
```

will take the first element of each list.

```py
df['Data'] = df.Data.map(lambda x: x[0] if x else '')
```

will not raise error if there is a 0-length list.

```py
df['Data'] = df.Data.map(lambda x: ','.join(x))
```

will turn a list of strings into a coma separated list.

Comment: Why do you assume a comma-separated list is the desired outcome? That string can't be used in any calculation without splitting it again

Comment: btw say if i want to creat a frequency plot for df['Data'], may i know how can it achieve it?

Comment: @hadija is it single labels only ? it matters a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you input your data as a string,

code :

```
data ='''data
[pineapple]
[pear]
[]
[chilli]'''

print(data.replace("[", "").replace("]", ""))
```

output :

```
data
pineapple
pear

chilli
```

If you input your data from a text file,

data.txt :

```
data
[pineapple]
[pear]
[]
[chilli]
```

code :

```
x= open("data.txt","r")
y= open("output.txt", "a")
# rewrite cleaned(replaced) strings to a new file
[y.write(str(i.replace("[","").replace("]",""))) for i in x.readlines()]
```

output.txt :

```
data
pineapple
pear

chilli
```